# How to find super-cheap MCUs?

Tags: microcontroller

I've heard stories about people finding super cheap MCUs on Chinese websites. How is this done? Are people just going to Alibaba? Do the websites show something different based on variables such as the IP address?

This is meant as a general question, but as an example I am currently searching for ATTINY806-M (i.e. the QFN version).

Bestow me with your wisdom!

Comment: You can find cheap knockoffs on Ali or cheap Chinese MCUs. But you are not going to find official warrantied distribution of name brand MCUs like ATTiny on there.

Comment: This is a "shopping question" so off-topic. Find a trustworthy distributor in China. ATTINY is not going to be "super cheap".  You would need a China, Taiwan or Korean manufacturer for that, and you'd probably have to buy development tools including an emulator (the least expensive parts tend to be OTP).

Comment: https://youtu.be/VYhAGnsnO7w

Comment: Just. dont. And if you do, don't come back here wondering why they don't work according to specifications.

Comment: As a more practical idea if you're trying to get cheap computing power, you might want to broaden your horizons and learn a variety of architectures or languages so you can select an MCU that does exactly what you need.  As an additional challenge, I wouldn't be surprised if some of the cheapest options weren't necessarily documented in english.  For one-off projects at a non-engineer skill level, it's often worth paying the extra for reliable, well documented product.

Comment: For designs produced in bulk, the unit cost decreases immensely for most parts and the substantial one time engineering costs of finding the cheapest possible reliable and adequate MCU has a better chance of being mitigated.  If you're producing in bulk though, you're probably selling the result, making potential low quality knockoffs less appealing and adding the concern of certification to even good quality knockoffs(which are probably what you are hoping for).

Comment: @KH I would say up to some thousands there is no point chasing cheap MCUs, at least not for designers in first-world countries.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany that confirms my guess.  Even if you save $4 per module over 1000 modules, that's only $4000 worth of engineering time, which doesn't sound like a lot to me if the goal is to use poorly documented off brand components and I think given that you'd also get bulk pricing on the reputable components, $4/module is maybe optimistic and then there's the cost of reduced consistency/reliability that could blow up on warranty issues too.

Comment: LCSC are a largish and apparently reputable Chinese based supplier. [HERE](https://lcsc.com/search?q=PADAUK) is their search results for Padauk microcontrollers (see below)  in ascending price order. They start at $US0.0527 (just over 5 cents) in 10's, dropping to 3.09 cents each in 10,000+ quantity. 677 page English language datasheet [here](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/PADAUK-Tech-PMS150C_C129127.pdf) . Such devices are typically OTP and you'll probably want to acquire a basic development system. LCSC stock 4 Padauk emulators [here](https://lcsc.com/search?q=padauk%20%20emulator) ...

Comment: the relevant one costing $US105 [here](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1811281202_PADAUK-Tech-PDK-3S-I-003_C341193.pdf) . Note that this is NOT a recommendation by me of LCSC or Padauk - I have not **YET** dealt with either - but I hope to.  || The bottom end processors may be more limited than you need, but they do a useful amount for 3 cents. || At about 11 cents each in 100's you get to an eg 16 pin SOP with PWM,  8 bit ADC, UART, SPI, I2C,LCD, key scan, 16 bit timer, 64 bytes RAM, 1 kW OTP, POR & brownout - ...

Comment: ... and using the same $105 [emulator](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1909181605_PADAUK-Tech-PMC271-S08_C317607.pdf)  || SO Are you buying a lot of potential work and possibly complete failure? Oh yes. Is it worthwhile? That depends. IN my case the target processor MUST cost around 10 cents or less in large volume. I may even find I can use a 6 cent processor :-). I may well not do the project at all. But, that gives you a guide.

Comment: [1] HACKADAY [making a 3 cent microcontroller useful](https://hackaday.com/2019/04/26/making-a-three-cent-microcontroller-useful/) , 
 [2] Here is an excellent overview of 8 different 3 cent uCs from 5 different suppliers -  [The “terrible” 3 cent MCU – a short survey of sub $0.10 microcontrollers](https://cpldcpu.wordpress.com/2019/08/12/the-terrible-3-cent-mcu/) In total, eight candidates from six different manufacturers where identified. A summary of the devices can be found in the table provided.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because ": Deemed a shopping question by some. I've addressed it as a query of how to achieve low cost manufacturing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is not meant to endorse or recommend any of the companies or brands mentioned. The aim is to show how low cost manufacturing can be achieved, and also touches lightly on the pitfalls.

**LCSC** are a largish and apparently reputable Chinese based supplier.
[HERE](https://lcsc.com/search?q=PADAUK) is their search results for Padauk microcontrollers (see below)  in ascending price order.
They start at $US0.0527 (just over 5 cents) in 10's, dropping to 3.09 cents each in 10,000+ quantity. 677 page English language datasheet for the lowest cost uC [here](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/PADAUK-Tech-PMS150C_C129127.pdf).
Such devices are typically (but not all) OTP and you'll probably want to acquire a basic development system.
LCSC stock 4 Padauk emulators [here](https://lcsc.com/search?q=padauk%20%20emulator)  - datasheet for the relevant one costing $US105 [here](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1811281202_PADAUK-Tech-PDK-3S-I-003_C341193.pdf).

Note that this is NOT a recommendation by me of LCSC or Padauk - I have not **YET** dealt with either - but I hope to.

The bottom end processors may be more limited than you need, but they do a useful amount for 3 cents.   For more performance, at about 11 cents each in 100's you get an eg 16 pin SOP uC with PWM,  8 bit ADC, UART, SPI, I2C,LCD, key scan, 16 bit timer, 64 bytes RAM, 1 kW OTP, POR & brownout - and using the same $105 [emulator](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1909181605_PADAUK-Tech-PMC271-S08_C317607.pdf)

So
Are you buying a lot of potential work and possibly complete failure?
Oh yes. I do not know how reliable Padauk (or any of the other sources mentioned below) are in maintaining supply, or at answering technical questions (in Chinese or English), or at assisting when technical issues arise. I do not know if errata are available, or if anyone cares if the spec is 'not quite met'. And more ... .

Is it worthwhile?
That depends. In my case the target processor MUST cost around 10 cents or less in large volume. I may even find I can use a 6 cent processor :-).
I may well not do the project at all.
But, that gives you a guide.

Here is a Hackaday article on using the lowest cost Padauk uC.
HACKADAY [making a 3 cent microcontroller useful](https://hackaday.com/2019/04/26/making-a-three-cent-microcontroller-useful/) ,

Here is an excellent overview of 8 different under 10 cent uCs from 5 different suppliers -
[The “terrible” 3 cent MCU – a short survey of sub $0.10 microcontrollers](https://cpldcpu.wordpress.com/2019/08/12/the-terrible-3-cent-mcu/)
In total, eight candidates from six different manufacturers were identified.
A summary of the devices can be found in the table below.

Click image to open a larger version

[image]

Comment: This is a really interesting answer and I learned a lot! Thanks!